# Python2 Scrape html with xpath

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

Consider a html page with 3 tables in it.

I want to loop through each table and at the same time to print something along if the content coresponds to something I want.

I need to keep track of the table I'm at.

As you see in the code below I have the `page` variable which is a html string.

I can return the content in all the tables at once(in an array).

I'd like to loop through them.

```
import __future__
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>cv</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>table1 td1</td>
            <td>table1 td2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>table2 td1</td>
            <td>table2 td2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>table3 td1</td>
            <td>table3 td2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
"""

soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser'))

tree = html.fromstring(soup)

tds = tree.xpath('//table/tr/td/text()')

for td in tds:
    print(td + '\n')

print('Ready !!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you need to process each table on its own?

```
for table in tree.xpath(".//table"):
    print("---  new table: ---")
    for td in table.xpath(".//td"):
        print(td)
```

Comment: It works, but what does that dot in front of the slashes mean? **.//** 
If I don't use it, the output is not desired.

Comment: it means that the xpath expression is evaluated relative to the current context node, `.//td` means to search for all descendants of the current node (it's a short form of `descendant::td`). An expression starting with a `/` always starts at the root node of the document, so `//td` selects all td nodes in the document, regardless of the context node.

Comment: Now I have another html document which has a lot of children and sub-chidlren elements.
I want to write the abosulte path to it, but I can't write all the sub-children because they are too many..
Consider the example above, and imagine the <td> tags would have had a lot of parents/grand-parents...
What would be the correct xpath to each td:
**xpath("/table.//td")** - is not working.
How can I retrieve the **td** from the context

Comment: You should ask a new question with the exact problem description and example input / expected output, comments are not the right place to ask new questions.